# Spring GraphQL - Validation error FieldsConflict returns different types 'Int' and 'String'"

Tags: java, spring-graphql

I just start migrating from com.graphql to Spring with graphql but I'm struggling with an error when running my query, here's the error :
"message": "Validation error (FieldsConflict@[getProductsByCategory/facets]) : 'values/value' : returns different types 'Int' and 'String'"

```
query {
    getProductsByCategory(
        lang: "fr",
        categoryCode:"C600_C605_C603"
        ) {
        facets {

            ...on RatingFacet {
                code
                description
                name
                multiSelect
                order
                values {
                    code
                    description
                    count
                    selected
                    value
                }
            }
            ...on ChoicesFacet {
                code
                description
                name
                multiSelect
                order
                values {
                    code
                    description
                    count
                    selected
                    value
                }
            }
        }
      
    }
}
```

The types definitions :

```
type CategorySearchResult {
    facets: [Facet!]!
   ...
}

union Facet =  RatingFacet | ChoicesFacet

interface FacetInterface {
    code: String!
    description: String
    name: String!
    multiSelect: Boolean
    order: Int!
}

interface FacetValue {
    code: String!
    description: String
    count: Int
    selected: Boolean!
}

type ChoicesFacet implements FacetInterface {
    ...
    values: [ChoiceFacetValue!]!
}
type ChoiceFacetValue implements FacetValue {
    ...
    value: String! <-- the error
}

type RatingFacet implements FacetInterface {
    ...
    values: [RatingFacetValue!]!
}
type RatingFacetValue implements FacetValue {
    ...
    value: Int! <-- the error
}
```

I don't understand what I missed and I don't know how to resolve it. Do I need to create a type resolver for my union ? Because it seems to refer to my types (RatingFacetValue and ChoiceFacetValue) that implements FacetValue

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this problem is due to Spring GraphQL, but rather a GraphQL Java upgrade. The graphql-java project has introduced changes in this area in 17.0+ and your schema is being rejected during the validation process.

I think your schema is breaking a validation rule implemented by graphql-java in its [OverlappingFieldsCanBeMerged](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/blob/master/src/main/java/graphql/validation/rules/OverlappingFieldsCanBeMerged.java). I'm not sure if your schema is invalid or if there is a bug in the [field merging checks](http://spec.graphql.org/draft/#sec-Field-Selection-Merging) implementation. I think it's worth creating a new graphql-java issue with a minimal project that only uses graphql-java and loads a minimal schema.